# Can't open large Jupyter Notebook file through local Jupyter Notebook after manipulation in Google Colab

Tags: synchronization, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

**I am struggling to open a large Jupyter Notebook file locally, after working on it in Google Colaboratory.**

I edited a pretty large Jupyter Notebook file with about 230 cells in **Google Colab**. Afterwards it seemed to have successfully synced to my local machine (macOS 10.14.1) through Google's Backup and Sync application. But now I receive the following error when I try to open the file **locally through my Anaconda Jupyter Notebook**:

```
Notebook failed to load

The error was:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
See the error console for details.
The notebook also failed validation:

Notebook validation failed: 'outputs' is a required property:
{
 "metadata": {
  "id": "t1y7q2Gnm3QT",
  "colab_type": "code",
  "colab": {
   "resources": {
    "http://localhost:8080/static/components/requirejs/require.js": {
     "data": ...(personal data)




# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
ipython                   6.1.0            py36hf612aae_1  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0            py36h241746c_0
```

I can open many other .ipynb files locally after editing them online in Google Colab on a different computer. The other files however had less cells and code. So could it be that there is some kind of size limitation for Google Colab?

My Jupyter version is 4.3.0.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. What version of Jupyter are you using to open the notebook?

Comment: @BobSmith, my Jupyter version is 4.3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @AmiF's input about the output field problem I found an easy fix for my needs:

In Google Colab, delete all output (>Edit >Clear all output). Make sure the file is saved in Google Colab (either automatically, or by >File >Save).

Once it is synced to my computer I am able to open it without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Colab sometimes stores large cell outputs out of band in separate Drive objects for various reasons. When you download the .ipynb file Colab stores in Drive directly such cells don't have an outputs field, instead they have a metadata.colab.output_embedded_package_id field (implementation detail, do not rely on this specific name). Jupyter is tripping over the missing outputs field.

You can work around this by using File->Download .ipynb in the colab UI.

Comment: Thanks Ami. It would still be great to resolve that syncing issue to automatically have a working file for offline editing on my computer.